# Fastest way to search a number in a list of ranges

Tags: c#, performance, algorithm, c#-4.0, optimization

I have the following code to find a match for a number in a list of ranges.

```
public class RangeGroup
{
    public uint RangeGroupId { get; set; }
    public uint Low { get; set; }
    public uint High { get; set; }
    // More properties related with the range here
}

public class RangeGroupFinder
{
    private static readonly List<RangeGroup> RangeGroups=new List<RangeGroup>();

    static RangeGroupFinder()
    {
        // Populating the list items here
        RangeGroups.Add(new RangeGroup { RangeGroupId = 0, Low = 1023238144, High = 1023246335 });
        RangeGroups.Add(new RangeGroup { RangeGroupId = 0, Low = 1023246336, High = 1023279103 });
        RangeGroups.Add(new RangeGroup { RangeGroupId = 0, Low = 1023279104, High = 1023311871 });
        RangeGroups.Add(new RangeGroup { RangeGroupId = 0, Low = 1023311872, High = 1023328255 });
        RangeGroups.Add(new RangeGroup { RangeGroupId = 0, Low = 1023328256, High = 1023344639 });
        RangeGroups.Add(new RangeGroup { RangeGroupId = 0, Low = 1023344640, High = 1023410175 });
        RangeGroups.Add(new RangeGroup { RangeGroupId = 0, Low = 1023410176, High = 1023672319 });
        RangeGroups.Add(new RangeGroup { RangeGroupId = 0, Low = 1023672320, High = 1023688703 });
        RangeGroups.Add(new RangeGroup { RangeGroupId = 0, Low = 1023692800, High = 1023696895 });
       // There are many more and the groups are not sequential as it can seen on last 2 groups
    }

    public static RangeGroup Find(uint number)
    {
        return RangeGroups.FirstOrDefault(rg => number >= rg.Low && number <= rg.High);
    }
}
```

The list of the RangeGroup consists about 5000000 items and the Find() method will be used a lot, so I'm looking for a faster way to make the search. It's no problem to change the structure of the data or split it in any way.

Edit:

All ranges are unique and added by in order of Low and they don't overlap.

Result:

Did a test using [ikh's code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11868837/fastest-way-to-search-a-number-in-a-list-of-ranges/11869161#11869161) and the result is approximately 7000 times faster than my code. The test code and results can be seen [here](https://gist.github.com/3297288).

Comment: Maybe using of the SortedList Class can improve performance a bit.

Comment: Are you looking to return any range that contains the number, or does the range have to match any criteria (e.g. was added earliest)?

Comment: Just the range that matches the criteria, all ranges are unique and added by in order of Low and they don't overlap.

Comment: I'd say use a tree structure sorted by low value instead of a list.

Comment: Could use a `SortedList` with a key of the Low, and binary search for the first key (low) greater than your search criteria and step back one index...

Comment: This might take a lot more memory, but if you had a 2-dimentional array with the rows sorted by the lows, and the columns sorted by the highs, you could probably reduce the time complexity of find

Comment: Btw, if you're searching, looking for the term "interval" might give you better results than "range". Maybe look for interval trees or something.

Comment: Performance comparison test between linq and binary search can be seen at the end of the question, thanks to everyone for the help :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you indicated that `RangeGroup`s are added in order of `RangeGroup.Low` and that they do not overlap, you don't need to do any further pre-processing.  You can do binary search on the `RangeGroups` list to find the range (warning: not fully tested, you'd need to check some edge conditions):

```
public static RangeGroup Find(uint number) {
    int position = RangeGroups.Count / 2;
    int stepSize = position / 2;

    while (true) {
        if (stepSize == 0) {
            // Worst case found it
            if(RangeGroups[position].High >= number && RangeGroups[position].Low <= number)
            {
                return ranges[position];
            }

            // Couldn't find it.
            return null;
        }

        if (RangeGroups[position].High < number) {
            // Search down.
            position -= stepSize;

        } else if (RangeGroups[position].Low > number) {
            // Search up.
            position += stepSize;

        } else {
            // Found it!
            return RangeGroups[position];
        }

        stepSize /= 2;
    }
}
```

The worst-case run time should be around O(log(N)), where N is the number of RangeGroups.

Comment: +1 for the insight - in the code - that binary search works on ranges - e.g check high when searching down, and low when searching up.

Comment: Actually, I was wrong about the quantity of the ranges, there are more than 5 million entries on my list, so I was wondering if using TPL would increase the performance (the server which will run this code has 64 cores). And how would the code look then? :)

Comment: @MennanKara If searching is the main thing that you do, then you may as well perform one search per core without any further modifications to the algorithm.  If you really want to make sure that each search takes as little time as possible, you could split `RangeGroups` into 64 subgroups and do parallel searches within each one on each core.  But you will not get 64x performance increase.

Comment: Thank you very much, added test results to the end of the question :)

Comment: This answer fails on the worst case, since the worst case results in a match being found in the loop where stepSize is 0 (previous loop changes the position to the final match). So, you have found your result and no more steps are needed, but it returns null anyways. I edited your answer with handling for that, please modify in whatever style you prefer.

Comment: Similarly this fails thanks to int truncation. On worst cases with an even number of groups, as it won't actually loop log(n) times. `stepSize = (int)Math.Round((float)stepSize / 2f);` ensures we loop the worst number of times

Answer (score 4):

[Interval trees.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree) were created exatcly for what you are asking for.

Comment: The benefit of interval trees over binary search is when you have overlapping intervals. There are no overlaps in this case. Binary search is simpler and sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

If you populate the list only once you can do a magic trick:

- [Sort the List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0zbh7b6.aspx)
- Use [BinarySearch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4e7fxsh.aspx)

Sort takes O(Nlog(N)) time and is only done once. Binary search takes O(log(N)), which takes at most 17 comparisons for 100.000 items.

Comment: plain binary search doesn't work in this situation.  You have both a low and a high part of the range to consider.

Comment: The list is already sorted, and as far as I understand, to be able to use the BinarySearch, I need to know what I'm looking for. Maybe if you can give an example for the BinarySearch it will help, thanks.

Comment: @MennanKara let me try to come up with a sample. Can you post a few instances of how you populate this list?

Comment: Your algorithm takes more than O(logn). You need that the value will be lower from max too.

Comment: @oleksii Added some sample data, normally I populate it from database at the Application_Start()

Comment: @MennanKara seems like IKH got it

Answer (score 1):

May be use a sorted list and do a binary search. That way you reduce the number of comparisons to O(logN)

Comment: Ok, Let me make it more clear. He is adding those intervals in order and they are not overlapping. So you have a sorted list.

Comment: continued: Searching a sorted list would take O(logN)

Comment: You cannot make it without checking all intervals . you can do it in logn only the intervals do not overlap.

Comment: @alinsoar It is mentioned in the question that the intervals do not overlap

Answer (score 0):

Sort the ranges twice, in two different arrays.  Once by least value in the range, once by greatest value in the range.  Then do two binary searches, saving the ranges that match either constraint.  Finally, do a set intersection of the two sets of possibilities.

Comment: Except its not necessary to go that far as ranges do not overlap.

Comment: Do you need 2 binary searches? I think he mentioned that none of the intervals are overlapping.