# storing multiple possibilities in settings

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have a scenario I cant work out the best way to approach in my head, I want it to give me the maximum extendability and avoid magic number coding.

Essentially a simplified example is this.

User inputs a number (lets say 5326)
My system will round this number down or up to the nearest "acceptable value" which comes from a list. I want this list to be configurable. Note also, different variables have different lists e.g.

acceptableHeight: 1000,2000,3000,4000
acceptableLength: 500,600,700,800

The best way i can think to store the values like this:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="acceptableHeight" value="1000,2000,3000,4000" />
    <add key="acceptableLength" value="500,600,700,800" />
</appSettings>
```

The logic i can think of is

1. Get value from config
2. Split by comma into a list of integers
3. sort the list (just in case)
4. some sort of search to find the nearest value (or use the end values)

but I am not 100% sure how...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11868837/fastest-way-to-search-a-number-in-a-list-of-ranges check the marked answer, I think this is the sort of thing you require

Answer (score 0):

You will want to store your list as a search tree.  - Creating the search tree will involve a sorting of the list.

A search tree is a tree that guarantees that an infix tree traversal will visit the stored values in a sorted order.  For a binary search tree, ie a tree where every node has at most two children, this means that every node has a value that is greater than all nodes in it's left subtree and smaller than all nodes in it's right subtree.

Preferrably a search tree should also be balanced, meaning that every subtree has close to equal depth.

Having a search tree in place it should then be trivial to determine the pair of closest largest and closest smaller acceptable value in O(log n) time.  And the step from their to the closest value is basic arithmetic.

-Several ways to implement search trees exists, see for example [AVL Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVL_tree) or [Red black tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red-black_tree).

An implementation of an avl tree in c# is here; [self-balancing-avl-tree](http://code.google.com/p/self-balancing-avl-tree/)

For your use case this is actually overkill since the tree only changes when you start up the program.  So you might want to implement your own search tree for this.

You can do this by first sorting your list and then recursivly:

- If list is empty do nothing.
- selecting the middle element of the list
- Creating a new node as the top node of the current tree
- Creating the left child by passing it the list of numbers before the selected element.
- Creating the right child by passing it the list of numbers after the selected element.

Comment: I have never used a search tree before. sounds interesting could you maybe elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

you can store it as a string and parse it as you suggested.

```
int[] acceptableHeight = AppSetting["acceptableHeight"].Split(',').Select(x => int.Parse(x));
```